# enable Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-chat

I would like to use FB messenger widget on my website, but I don't want people are able to use it from my FB page.
Is it possible to enable FB Messenger on an external site, but keep it disabled on the FB Page?

Comment: No, I don’t think that is possible. The widget enables the user to chat _with your page_, so if you disabled chatting with your page, on your page, the whole thing would not make much sense any more to begin with.

Comment: thanks for the answer, you're right!! since FB manages messages if I'll disable this function I disable the whole messaging system